# React Native Android app crashes when receiving push notifications

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

I'm having major issues finding out why my Android application suddenly began crashing when it receives push notifications. I'm using `react-native-push-notification` and the app registers a token all fine, but when a push notification is sent to the phone I get an error saying:

```
W/ReactNativeJS(  917): Warning: Native component for "SharedElementTransition" does not exist
W/ReactNativeJS(  917): Warning: Native component for "MKTouchable" does not exist
W/ReactNativeJS(  917): Warning: Native component for "MKSpinner" does not exist
W/ReactNativeJS(  917): Warning: Native component for "TickView" does not exist
E/ReactNativeJS(  917): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNFSManager.RNFSFileTypeRegular')
```

This is all very cryptic. The `onNotification` method has no content so this makes me wonder if there is some other error with the message being sent.

Any suggestions on how this can be solved would be appreciated.

Comment: hi I am not a react native developer but are those warning or errors?
also if they are errors the most common reason is there is a library or more missing try searching the cause for those error and goodluck.

Comment: @Hala.M Hi, they're in the debugging console. No luck trying to find others with the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving the "MKTouchable" and "TickView" does not exist warnings earlier and was able to solve it by using the following steps:

1. In my terminal I installed rnpm `npm install -g rnpm`
2. `rnpm link` or if you know specifically which library that's not properly liked like in my case `react-native-material-kit`, do `rnpm link react-native-material-kit`
3. Finally restart your react-native packager using `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android` for android.

   - Note: I am running on a mac building for iOS, commands may be different on your system.

Comment: rnpm is part of react-native cli, you should not be using rnpm